# How to specify a startup folder in the open command to launch MacVim?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

If I want to open a file in MacVim from the terminal. I use the following the command `open -a MacVim --args filepath`.

It disregards my working dir so I need to always specify the full path when opening a file. When I do `open -a MacVim --args piano.py` it assumes the file is in $HOME no matter what is my $PWD.

It is just an example. It applies to any application. Macos seems to not have the "Startup Folder" or "Start in" feature for executables in Windows.

I took a look in the mvim implementation.

```
 # Note: this isn't perfect, because any error output goes to the
 # terminal instead of the console log.
 # But if you use open instead, you will need to fully qualify the
 # path names for any filenames you specify, which is hard.
 exec "$binary" -g $opts ${1:+"$@"}
```

Can I get MacVim to accept a startup path?

Comment: Just played around with it a bit myself. It seems to work if MacVim is *not* running, but it doesn't open a new file/window into an already running MacVim.

Comment: I do`killall` before. It does work, but the problem is that the paths can't be relative to the current dir. Maybe I should have formulated it otherwise.

Comment: Then do :-) I don‘t think it‘s an issue with `open` though (because it works with relative paths if MacVim is not running).

Comment: If you're using MacVim, you can also use their `mvim` script, which acts like the `gvim` command.

Comment: It doesn't work with relative paths is MacVim is not running. It tries to open the same file on `/Users/username/`

Comment: @SilverWolf yeh, this is the solution.

Comment: Also, `open -a MacVim <file>` works just fine, no need to use `--args`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using MacVim, and it doesn't seem to be a problem with the `open` command:

**MacVim comes with its own script called `mvim`.**

You can use it just like `gvim` to open files in the MacVim GUI, or pass `-v` to it to open in regular text mode with the ability to use `:gui` later.

---

Also, you can just use `open -a MacVim <file>`, no need to use `--args`. It'll figure it out just as if you double-clicked on the file in the Finder.